# Browser game engine - windows service, scheduled tasks, thread, cache tasks?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, game-engine

I'm in the process of creating browser game (category football manager) and I need to know how I should implement tasks like finances update or football matches.

I know there are some possibilities:

- windows service
- thread in global.asax
- scheduled tasks
- solution with cache - https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/

I could only buy a shared hosting so my possibilities are limited to thread, solution with cache and scheduled tasks, but I don't really know how it works and if I could use it or not e.g. I heard that site in IIS could be killed any time so if I use a thread it could not be great when there are matches played. Or if I use scheduled task I don't know if I can run there something that long like e.g. playing thousand of matches at some time.

Does anyone have any experience in browser games development?

Comment: If you need heavily stateful interaction, WCF is the way to go. Of course, shared hosting may limit you in that regard. You can host WCF in IIS, but as you mentioned worker process management can be cumbersome. Do you have any other hosting options? Even a cheap VPS solution would open up a _lot_ of possibilities

Comment: There's no such thing like cheap VPS solution :D Maybe in future, but for now I'm stuck with shared hosting ;)

Comment: @David, how is WCF a stateful solution?   Its just a remove service framework.

Comment: @jfar It's not, if he hosts it in IIS. If he were able to host it on the box, it could be hosted in a number of ways to provide state; WAS, Windows Service or Console App